# Sudo apt-get update problem, it is always showing me "404 error" & "release is not available"

Tags: ubuntu-19.04

I know there are many answers to this but i already tried many solutions on internet but not a single one worked for me .
Im using Ubuntu 19.04 in an Oracle virtual Box.

```
ather@ather-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for ather: 
Ign:1 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Err:3 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 195.135.221.134 80]
Ign:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

[Software Configuration is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5BTm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 19.04 is out-dated. So all packages for Ubuntu 19.04 is found in old-release section.

This may cause this 404 error.

You can refer [this](https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-fix-apt-get-update-error-on-ubuntu.html) post to solve error.